# ng-include ruins the bootstrap ul li dropdown formatting

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-include

Hi I am trying to reproduce the following piece of code which produces a simply dropdown menu in bootstrap:

```
        <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

However, I want to be able to include the li tags with angularJS's ng-include...

```
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <ng-include src="'partials/thisView.html'"></ng-include>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

and then in thisView I would have:

```
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
```

However the problem is that when I do this, the li tag's parent tag is not the ng-include tag and not the ul tag which causes the formatting to look poorly (none of the bootstrap classes/CSS are applied).

So the DOM looks like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu role="menu">
    <ng-include src="'partials/thisView.html'" class="ng-scope">                            <li class="ng-scope"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
             <li class="ng-scope"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
             <li class="ng-scope"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
             <li class="divider ng-scope"></li>
             <li class="ng-scope"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
             <li class="divider ng-scope"></li>
             <li class="ng-scope"><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ng-include>
</ul>
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Any luck with the below answer yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can utilize attribute restriction instead of element restriction (as [ng-include](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L3) supports `ECA`)  and specify `ng-include` as attribute.

i.e

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-include="'partials/thisView.html'">
  </ul>
```

Comment: wasted 30 minutes because of this behaviour. Thanks.